# How can i generate report using appium+python?

Tags: python, testing, appium, functional-testing

I am currently working on a mobile application with appium with python. There are a lot of options for every file selection in that. Currently checking if processing all the types of files are possible in that. So, there are a lot of combinations for each file. I successfully managed to access through all of the combinations using nested loops and some basic algorithms. Currently generating the combinations and their results in a csv sheet through JSON format. I need some help about how can I generate good test report in a professional way for each of these combination.

Answer (score 1):

allure report

Allure Reporting Tool

Install the allure from pip command

`pip3 install allure-pytest`

Download allure.bat file

https://docs.qameta.io/allure/

2.1.4. Manual installation

https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/qameta/allure/allure-commandline/

Set the environmental variable

Mac

i) open terminal and type `vim ~/.zshrc`

ii) `export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/allure/bin`

iii) and open new terminal and type `allure --version` to find allure version

Run Allure command
Mac
`py.test --alluredir='/Users/rajat/Documents/AllureReport/AppiumPythonLogs' -v –s test_PytestAllure.py`

window
`py.test --alluredir='C:\BT\BTBusiness\AllureReports' -v –s test_PytestAllure.py`

To create Report
`allure serve "C:\BT\BTBusiness\PythonBTB\BTBReport\AllureReports`